# How can I bind a tab record to a header record?

Tags: acumatica

I have a form with a General Information tab.  There are fields in the header and General Info tab that are bound to the same view (and thus should be a part of the same record in the Cache/Database).  However, when I insert, it creates 2 records in the same table.  One contains only the values for the fields in the header, the other contains only the values for the fields in the tab.  I need those to be bound to the same record.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I got around this by declaring a second view, binding that view to the main view through the key, and assigning the tab to use the second view as its data source.

I got the idea from the EmployeeMaint BLC, where the General Info tab is distinguished from the header view using these 2 views:

```
public PXSelectJoin<EPEmployee, LeftJoin<GL.Branch, On<GL.Branch.bAccountID, Equal<EPEmployee.parentBAccountID>>>, Where<EPEmployee.parentBAccountID, IsNull, Or<MatchWithBranch<GL.Branch.branchID>>>> Employee; 
public PXSelect<EPEmployee, Where<EPEmployee.bAccountID, Equal<Current<EPEmployee.bAccountID>>>> CurrentEmployee;
```

Consider that the header in the EP203000 page uses the Employee view, while the General Info tab uses the CurrentEmployee view.

...however, even though I got this code straight out of their system, I've been personally advised by Acumatica's support team NOT to declare 2 views that use the same primary DAC.  Any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, you'll see this pattern in many screens of the application. I'd be curious to see how their recommandation was written - they might have meant something else.

Comment: That's what Ruslan told me.

Comment: This is actually the correct and the only viable way to achieve your goal. In addition to being used all over the application it is also shown in the T200 training AFAIR, so have no worries about using it.